# trying to update all rows with defferent values

Tags: sql, sql-server

when i'm doing it for one row its worked

```
update test set counte = 
(select  cOUNT(*)as counte from en_cours ,
test where DATEDIFF(DAY, en_cours.date, test.date)=0 
and  test.date='2019-11-13' group by test.date)
where test.date='2019-11-13'
```

but when i'm doing it for all rows

```
update test set counte =
(select  COUNT(*) from en_cours ,
test where DATEDIFF(DAY, en_cours.date, test.date)=0  
group by test.date) 
where test.date= (select  CONVERT(date , en_cours.date) from en_cours)
```

they said

> "Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression."

any help please

Comment: The error is very explicit here. What about the error don't you understand, as your sub query clearly has **2** columns in it (and could well be returning multiple rows).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error message is self explanatory. You can not set a condition like WHERE 10 = (A list of Integer like - 10,20,30). When you are using =, !=, <, <= , >, >= signs, the sub query must return a single value where as your  query is returning more than 1 value and the error lies there. You can use CTE as below to achieve your requirement-

```
WITH CTE AS(
    select  test.date,COUNT(*) T
    from en_cours 
    INNER JOIN test 
        ON en_cours.date = test.date
    group by test.date
)

update A
SET A.counte = B.T
FROM Test A
INNER JOIN CTE B ON A.Date = B.Date
```